# Error:Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

when is tried to get `state` data i get this TypeError:

> Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

```
public addreq=(userId)=>{
 let data:any ={
 senderId:this.userInfo.userId,
 recevierId:userId,
 state:'request'   
 }
this.socketS.requestsend(data)

this.users['source']=data
console.log('addreq',this.users)  
};
<div class="modal-body" > 
    <div *ngFor ="let user of users | userfilter:search; let i = index;" [ngClass]="{'active':user}">
   <div class="text-center"  *ngIf="user.userId!==userInfo.userId">
       <p>{{user.username}}</p> 
       <button class='btn btn-primary' [ngClass]="{'hide':user.source.state==='request'}" (click)="addreq(userId)">add</button>

   </div>      
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
this.users['source']=data
```

and add

```
for(user of this.users) user.source=data;
```

Comment: thank you for replying immediately, as you can in code i used `<div *ngFor ="let user of users | userfilter:search; let i = index;" [ngClass]="{'active':user}">` for looping array so i user `use.source`

Comment: One thing that might be possible is see your function is running only after the button click. So before you click the button the `users.source` variable does not exist yet. Also you are setting the `source` property to users which is the array of objects and not to the individual user elements which are present inside the users array. What do you see from the console.log output?

Comment: sorry for late replt here is the console.log data`(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}, source: {…}]
source:
recevierId: undefined
senderId: "qOQ4SBupg"
state: "request"`

Comment: yes. You see the users array here has 3 user objects and one source property. What you are accessing is the source property from those 3 user objects which does not exist. I will edit my answer. Check if that works.